# Given the current date, how to get the last day of the last 24 months?

Tags: javascript

Regards,

Given the current date, I would like to know the last day of the month for the last 24 months. Im trying to get an output similar to this:

> 30/11/2018 for current month -1
>
> 31/10/2018 for current month -2
>
> ...
>
> 31/12/2016 for current month -24

I've tried searching trough SO but I couldn't find a similar question.

Any help? :)

Edit: Based on Jalees code, I've come with this code, that I think it does what I need:

```js
for(i=0;i<24;i++)
{
 d = new Date();
 d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + (1 - (i + 1)));
 d.setDate(0);
 $('#aaaaa').append($('<option>', {value: 'x', text: d.getDate() + '/' + (((d.getMonth() + 1).length == 1) ? '0'+''+(d.getMonth() + 1) : d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear()}));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="aaaaa"></select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages.

Comment: I should have been more careful redacting the question, sorry about that. Wish you could remove the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loop index to subtract from current month to build a new date for each month and set the day to zero to get last day of prior month

Example using `Array#from()`:

```js
const curr = new Date();

function getPrevMonth(_,i){
   const prev = new Date(curr.getFullYear(), curr.getMonth()-i, 0)
   return [prev.getDate(), prev.getMonth()+1, prev.getFullYear()].join('/')// format as desired
}
const months = Array.from({length:24}, getPrevMonth);

console.log(months)
```

Comment: Charlie, that code is much more elegant than mine, and works great too :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this technique
. for month February you can use 1 and for March 2 and continue.

```
var month = 0; // January
var d = new Date(2008, month + 1, 0);
alert(d); // last day in January
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot that approach Jalees.